# Make a Google web app that's triggered from a Google Spreadsheet form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have a Google Apps script (written in a Google Spreadsheet) that creates a separate calendar and events for it with respect to a university course and the university calendar. The GUI is a Spreadsheet form, which triggers the execution of my script. The script gets its input from the spreadsheet form entry.

The trouble I have is that I can't easily deploy my solution to other users. Yes, they can make a copy of my sheet/form/scripts, so that they can run it on their account. Several problems, however, result from this approach:

- triggers don't get copied - this is because authorization to access local info (calendars, contacts, etc.) must be given by the users before a trigger is enabled. So users have to re-connect the form submission trigger to the Apps Script for it to work (this is not user friendly).
- if I change the code of my apps script, the users are using a copy and won't see the changes.

The solution seems to be [Google Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps), but from what I've read, I can't re-use the form-based GUI of my approach. Or can I?

Google Spreadsheet Forms have the advantage that they are very easy to create, and you can already specify what fields are mandatory, etc. I don't want to have to re-write all of this in a complicated GUI front-end to my Google Apps Script (**Edit: even the [GUI builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder) tool seems way more complicated than a Spreadsheet Form**), yet I want other users to be able to create the calendars and events in their own Google accounts. Is there a way to keep my form, but have it hooked to a Web App version of my code?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the form on a google sites (intranet). This way, any user having access, will be able to use the form as it is. All logic you created will remain the same.

Creating a script however will allow the user to execute the script "under their login", thus enabling access to calendars, contacts......

Comment: My form is already on an intranet, but requires no authentication. Are you saying that by requiring authentication to the form, the script will execute under the account of the authenticated user?

Comment: It's not possible to deploy a script, made in a spreadsheet, as a web app without changing the code. If they share calendars with you (because you're the admin....of the script), than by adding another column to the form to contain the user name, you can access their stuff.

Comment: Please supply more details if you want me to find your answer useful for my question.